# How to marshal JavaFX Image and save its absolute path in xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, javafx-8

So I've been working on a address manager app and came across a situation where **I've to save each person's image, with other data, into an xml file** on local disk. How to achieve **marshalling/unmarshalling of image**?

Here is the *person class.*

```
//relevant imports ..


public class Person {

    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty lastName;
    private final StringProperty address;
    private final IntegerProperty zipCode;
    private final SimpleStringProperty contact;
    private final StringProperty city;
    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday;
    private final ObjectProperty<Image> image;

     //constructors
    public Person() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {

        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        this.city = new SimpleStringProperty("Amroha");
        this.contact = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        this.zipCode = new SimpleIntegerProperty(244221);
        this.birthday = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(LocalDate.of(1993, Month.JANUARY, 6));
        this.image=new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>(null);
    }

    // other getters & setters..

    public void setImage(Image image) {

        this.image.set(image);
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image.get();

    }

}
```

I have created this *XML adapter* for parsing image into xml where i want to *store image file path* as a *key*

```
public class ImageAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String,Image>{

    @Override
    public Image unmarshal(String filePath) throws Exception {

        return new Image("file :"+filePath);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Image v) throws Exception {

        //don't know what to do here..

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Image.url` property is only available starting with JavaFX 9. In also doesn't work for images created from an `InputStream`.

Recovering the image paths in JavaFX 8 requires you to store the URLs yourself when loading the images. You could use a `Map` for this purpose:

```
private final Map<Image, String> imageSources = new WeakHashMap();

public Image loadImage(String url) {
    Image image = new Image(url);
    imageSources.put(image, url);
    return image;
}

public String getURLFromImage(Image image) {
    retrun imageSources.get(image);
}
```

This has the drawback that the data is spread accross multiple files though. Moving the data to a different machine would require all referenced files to be moved to and unless you implement additional logic to make the urls relative, you'll get absolute paths making the data even harder to move...

---

You could store the image data as base64 encoded string in the xml itself though:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Image>{

    @Override
    public Image unmarshal(String data) throws Exception {
        return data == null || data.isEmpty() ? null : new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(data)));
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Image v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return "";
        }
        BufferedImage bImg = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(v, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bImg, "png", bos);

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bos.toByteArray());
    }
}
```